# Wordpress Guest Login Redirect on view posts

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a wp site and I try to force guest to login/register before viewing only SINGLE POSTS.(not pages, archives etc.).

I have this function:

```
// Redirect users who arent logged in...
function login_redirect() {

    // Current Page
    global $pagenow;

    // Check to see if user in not logged in and not on the login page
    if(!is_user_logged_in() && $pagenow != 'wp-login.php')
          // If user is, Redirect to Login form.
          auth_redirect();
}
// add the block of code above to the WordPress template
add_action( 'wp', 'login_redirect' );
```

The problem with this function is that it redirects guest to login when they view any page/post/etc. Can someone help me modify this function to redirect only on viewing single posts?
Thanks, Iasmina

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
   function login_redirect() {
   // Current Page
   global $pagenow;

   // Check to see if user in not logged in and not on the login page
         if (!is_user_logged_in() && $pagenow != 'wp-login.php' && is_single() && !is_home()) {              
    auth_redirect();
       }
}

// add the block of code above to the WordPress template
add_action('wp', 'login_redirect');
```

Comment: Great, don't forget to accept my answer by clicking the tick on the left!

Answer (score 0):

Add another conditional tag to the if statement

```
if(!is_user_logged_in() && $pagenow != 'wp-login.php' && is_single())
```

[`is_single()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single)

Comment: You also need to check if its home page or not as he needs to redirect only in case of a post page!

Comment: Not entirely true, the `is_single` only returns true if a single post of any post type except attachment and page post types is being displayed.